# jQuery AJAX GET works on desktop browsers, but not on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have a very simple script:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/s_basket_view_basket_ajax.php",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#myDebug').append(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $('#myDebug').append('<p>status code: '+xhr.status+'</p>');
            $('#myDebug').append('<p>error: ' + error + '</p>');
            $('#myDebug').append('<p>xhr.responseText:</p>');
            $('#myDebug').append('<div>'+xhr.responseText + '</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

This works on a desktop browsers, but is returning a status code: 0 on iPhone & Android browsers.

It is NOT a cross domain request - the script runs in a folder (e.g. www.mydomain.com/scripts/)

I appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: `It is NOT a cross domain request` - that's actually obvious from the URL :p

Comment: you say you get status code 0 ... any `error` and/or `responseText` at all?

Comment: I like being obvious :) No error or responseText at all.

Comment: have you tried various browsers on Android? not sure if you can on iPhone ... note: sometimes even being obvious can be ignored :p

Comment: Yes - standard, Firefox & Dolphin.

Comment: looks like problem is with url it self

Comment: @AshishPatel - why would the URL work on a desktop but not in a mobile?